# C2DM 411. That’s an error. POST requests require a Content-length header

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

Am working on a push notification that makes user of C2DM. I have been able to obtain the users registration id, authentication token from Google. But when i try to send the message i receive this error from google "411. That’s an error. POST requests require a Content-length header".

```
function send($deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) {
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
$reg_id = $deviceRegistrationId; // Registration ID
$device_id = "1"; 

$data = array(
'registration_id' => trim($reg_id),
'collapse_key' => 'ck_'.trim($device_id),
'data.arg' => trim($messageText)
);
$dataStr = http_build_query($data);

$headers = array(
'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.$_SESSION['google'],
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length: '.strlen($dataStr)
);

// Prepare the cURL request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,            CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
curl_setopt($ch,     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,           CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataStr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);

// Send the request and echo the response body
$response = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
echo "Reponse is ".$response;
}
```

Also below is the result i get when i output values of curl to a file

> About to connect() to android.apis.google.com port 443 (#0)
>     Trying 74.125.39.139... * connected
>   Connected to android.apis.google.com (74.125.39.139) port 443 (#0)
>   successfully set certificate verify locations:
>     CAfile: none
>    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
>   SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
>   Server certificate:
>      subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.google.com
>      start date: 2011-11-10 07:48:51 GMT
>      expire date: 2012-11-10 07:58:51 GMT
>      subjectAltName: android.apis.google.com matched
>      issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority
>      SSL certificate verify ok.
>   POST /c2dm/send HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: android.apis.google.com
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAMIAAADlJmeJmrTjmzdAbt1HiMvvVj_vdSduVXrkEFk_D19OG0o->FIn1ZzJ25d3MZfDTK2QErF_jEFAndPgC3RoGif6V-gs9w3-FA7VaEWd62qNPnscsqi1j6R0b0J5vtOwGItNmuXm5n1MZrOZ4sd3yx_D95rtzriymmyhilzLWNAyNjPO6FsmX-4Ty_3OwPaw02qe_oHeSvTNt7s6SW-_kT-T1hdJuywCoSf5p2esSzk9sUj9YDwtEXPneDIaB1z2Qy6NcMBjYY8X185GctBttXrjd
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length: 207
>
> HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
>   HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 11791
>
> Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2011 12:16:06 GMT
>
> Server: GFE/2.0
>
> Closing connection #0

how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
function send ($deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) {

  $reg_id = $deviceRegistrationId; // Registration ID
  $device_id = "1"; 

  // Build request body
  $data = array (
    'registration_id' => trim($reg_id),
    'collapse_key' => 'ck_'.trim($device_id),
    'data.arg' => trim($messageText)
  );
  $dataStr = trim(http_build_query($data));

  // Headers for the request
  $headers = array(
    'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.trim($_SESSION['google']),
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: '.trim(strlen($dataStr)),
    'Connection: close'
  );

  // Prepare the cURL request
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
               CURLOPT_URL => "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
              CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $dataStr,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
  ));

  // For debugging
  //$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
  //curl_setopt($ch,        CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  //curl_setopt($ch,         CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  //curl_setopt($ch,         CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);

  // Send the request and echo the response body
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  //fclose($f);
  echo "Reponse is ".$response;

}
```

Comment: i tried what you posted but it is still not working. Same error message.

Comment: Try slightly corrected code from above. The problem, however, may be due the fact that the data you are sending is incorrect (like the unused variables `$msgType` and `$messageText`, or the use of the empty `$message` variable, which will result in an empty `data.arg`.

Comment: i have changed corrected all the errors, $messageText is used instead, $authCode ha been taken out of function parameters but still not working

Comment: Very odd - I can't see any obvious problem with your current code. Try adding `Connection: close` to the request headers and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @EdemKofi After doing some reading and playing around, I edited my answer with a new code that will hopefully work. Let me know how you get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing related to this is here http://codershelpingcoders.com.Have a look

Comment: Hi, this page is down and I have same error than above, could you point me about the solution?

Comment: This was about the YouTube Sample code.You may find it over here https://github.com/techie28/YouTubeUploadPHP